# Remove module as library from git using android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I was using a project as module dependency in Android Studio. I no longer now need it. So I removed the dependency from `build.gradle` file and then committed and pushed it. When i take a fresh check out using git in Android Studio, i am able to see that module, even though that is not being used by my project. If i check on the git site, the folder is still there. I think i need to delete it from the cache of the git which maintain the history of this. But I do not know the commands to run in the Android studio terminal to completely remove it from git respository.

Project Structure

```
Project
|
-app
   -build.gradle(removed dependency of module 1)
-Module1
-Module2
-module3
-settings.gradle(removed module1)
```

Want to remove module1 from the git. Please let me know the commands.

Comment: Please give the commands you used to remove the dependency and what you expected to see as a result of those commands.